# Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component - Socket.IO

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

For some reason, it gives an error, although this fix works on almost all classes, but doesn’t want to.

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.
>   This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.
>   To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the
>   componentWillUnmount method.
>       in Test (at app.js:212)

```
class Test extends React.Component {
    _isMounted = false;

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            timestamp: '-'
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this._isMounted = true;

        if (this._isMounted) {
            subscribeToTimer((err, timestamp) => this.setState({
                timestamp
            }));
        }
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this._isMounted = false;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="timer">
                <p className="timer-intro">
                    This is the timer value: {this.state.timestamp}
                </p>
            </div>
        );
    } 
}
```

Func:

```
import openSocket from 'socket.io-client';

const socket = openSocket('http://blablabla:3001');
function subscribeToTimer(cb) {
    socket.on('timer', timestamp => cb(null, timestamp));
    socket.emit('subscribeToTimer', 1000);
}

export { subscribeToTimer };
```

Server:

```
const io = require('socket.io')();

io.on('connection', (client) => {
    client.on('subscribeToTimer', (interval) => {
        console.log('client is subscribing to timer with interval ', interval);
        setInterval(() => {
            client.emit('timer', Date.now());
        }, interval);
    });
});

const port = 3001;
io.listen(port);
console.log('listening on port ', port);
```

Comment: You should unsubscribe in `componentWillUnmount`. Your `if (this._isMounted)` is pointless as it is set to true in the line before that.

Comment: I'm having the same problem using socket.io. The response from server is received after the component unmounted. Did you solved this??

Comment: @tkausl How to do that? how do I unsubscribed componentWillUnmout? can you provide a minimal example that works

Comment: It has been answered quite a few times. Either put `socket.off('name-of-your-event')` or try `socket.close()` in the `componentWillUnmount()`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53459912/react-component-socket-io-unnecessary-connection